# Rails new - wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, arguments, new-operator

I have the following inside a `new` method of an `orders_controller`

```
@order = Order.new
```

Rails gives me the following error:

`wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`

```
app/models/order.rb:2:in `<class:Order>'
app/models/order.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:33:in `new'
```

I am using Rails 3.0.5

Thanks!

Edit: order.rb can be found below

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => destroy

  PAYMENT_TYPES = [ "Check", "Credit card", "Purchase order" ]

  validates :name, :address, :email, :pay_type, :presence => true
  validates :pay_type, :inclusion => PAYMENT_TYPES

  def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)
    cart.line_items.each do |item|
      item.cart_id = nil
      line_items << item
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your `order.rb` file?

Comment: Show your Order class source, there is probably a new or initialize method defined somewhere in there.

Comment: The Ruby error is actually very descriptive. You supplied no arguments to the constructor while at least one argument is required. If you post the source to orders.rb, we can help figure out what the required argument should be.

Comment: I posted the source to order.rb!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. You missed a `:` in the `:destroy`

Change `:dependent => destroy` in line 2 to `:dependent => :destroy`. It should work.

Comment: That's what I just wrote above...no need to respost an answer

Comment: @joshim5..I posted my answer before u posted...check the time of posting..it is not a repost..infact it is urs which is a repost ;)

Comment: that's incorrect.  I posted mine 2 minutes before yours.

Comment: @joshim5..please click the `oldest` tab...you can see my answer first..and you can check the time of posting also by keeping the cursor near the name section in each answer and seeing the tooltip..and if that is not enough, check this [screenshot](http://www.flickr.com/photos/67059624@N02/6105391093/)..you can see my answer was posted 3 minutes before you posted..SO site says so..if u dont believe..it is fine with me ;)

Answer (score 2):

The first declaration in `order.rb` should read:

```
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
```